# Passing arguments to application methods from view forms

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have previously populated web forms to create model objects but what I am wanting to do  is pass an arguement to an application method from the view. In my view:

```
<form>
      <input type="text" id="arg"></br>
      <input type="submit" onsubmit="@routes.Application.search(@arg)" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But this seems incorrect. Is there some other method of handling the HTML input yourself by using the scala helpers. The method *search* takes a string as an argument and is included in the routes table.

Answer (score 0):

Your input **need** to has a name, then you'll be able to bind it from request without problems.

Comment: I added this, it does seem to be a step in the right direction, the URL changes so that I get arg=test but it doesnt seem to call the application method.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "@" before arg. You don't need it there, the first "@" in the method call is enough to start a Scala code snipped.

```
<form>
      <input type="text" mame="arg" id="arg"></br>
      <input type="submit" onsubmit="@routes.Application.search(arg)" value="Submit">
</form>
```